# mac mini flashing mouse repetitive sound wont let me click on stuff

Tags: audio, mouse

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5NeoGTkkZ4&index=2&list=PLTlfSplem0iX3CLphwxx5fPGD98ydgbpZ

okay so basically half a week ago my computer would start making weird sounds and not letting me click on anything. pretty sure that's not normal for macs, but anyway, i have searched long and hard for the solution tried restarting my computer, using all the computer repair tools built into the mac
literally nothing has helped. now i have two main theories, either my computer has been cursed or hive a virus. no clue what to do.

any help at all would be very very very much appreciated
Ps: i had to use someone else's computer to post this (yes it's that bad)

Comment: Have you tried resetting the PRAM and SMC?

Comment: Yes i tried that, still not working

Comment: Have you tried the hardware test?

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth keyboard that has some things laying on them? This is the sound if keys being pressed down forever.

Comment: no i do not have a bluetooth keyboard

Answer (score -1):

i eventually just decided to do a factory reset, it worked.

Comment: What's a "factory reset" on a Mac?  Do you mean wipe the drive and reinstall from scratch?